# assign variable name to an object when variable is assigned

Tags: python

In python, variable have name while object do not (as several variable can point to the same object)

But is there a way to add/modify the `name` property of an object when it is assigned to a variable.

Ideally, something that would work like this:

```
spam = MagicObject()
print(spam.name) # output: "spam"
ham = spam
print(spam.name) # output: "ham"
```

Edit: In fact, I Don't really mind if the second printing is "ham" or "spam" as I don't really plan to have several variable pointing on the same objet. I just want the object to have a name whatever the scenario.

My idea is to create some kind of parameter file with as little writing as possible. So that this simple code:

```
person_id = PrimaryKey()
```

would create a PrimaryKey object and automaticaly name it "person_id"

Comment: No. `spam` has virtually no way of knowing that it has been assigned to anything, let alone know the assignee's name

Comment: Try with `copy` : https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: @PhxDev Unrelated at all to what OP is trying to do

Comment: `map(attrgetter('name'), [MagicObject(), MagicObject()])` – now what?

Comment: Also, what do you expect to happen if we do `a, b = spam, spam`?

Comment: Variables are merely *placeholders in an algorithm.* Their specific name should carry no significance, especially since you're sometimes constrained in the names you can use for a given variable and hence *cannot* assign it any specific meaning.

Comment: This is doable with class attributes, e.g. `class Foo: bar = Baz()`, and then a lot meta class or `__init__` magic… But for standalone variables, it's a bad idea.

Comment: OK…. So what I can do is `param.person_id = PrimaryKey()` and it will create and atribute `PrimaryKey` with the name "person_id". Thanks folks!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is as closest as you can achieve to what you are trying to do. It is inefficient and abusing `globals` and `properties`. Also, if `MagicObject` is complex it will need to implement `__eq__` (and probably `__hash__` as well).

This is a **hack** and should probably not be used in production.

```
 class MagicObject:
    @property
    def name(self):
        return [k for k, v in globals().items() if v == self]

a = MagicObject()
print(a.name)
b = a
print(a.name)
c = a
print(a.name)
del b
print(a.name)
```

Outputs

```
['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'c']
```

Also keep in mind that in Python < 3.7 the order of the list will be arbitrary since dictionaries have no order.

Comment: This is certainly unefficient, but I see no abuse here. `Globals` and `property` are totally valid tools to me. You can make it an non arbitrary list with `return sorted([k for k, v in globals().items() if v == self])`. Anyway, I Don't really plan to have several variable for an object. I just wanted to clarify that the object can have a unique (if somewhat arbitrary) name whatever happen.

Comment: I think you should replace `v==self`with `v is self`. No need to redefine `__eq__` that way and it is more logical anyway

Comment: @Madlozoz Not necessarily, it is totally depending on the implementation of `MagicObject` and what you are trying to achieve as I explained in my answer. In case `__eq__` is not defined, `==` is falling back to `is` anyway

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to write an ORM. Two suggestions:

- Don't. Use one already written, SQLAlchemy, for instance.
- If you're doing something else, or you really want to go down that rabbit hole, check how those ORMs do it, most probably with a MetaClass.